# Viewpager images are disappear when i scroll down and up the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I want to use ViewPager inside of RecyclerView(for multiple images like instagram). But when I scroll down and up the RecyclerView, the images are disappear. I think my problem is create a new Adapter inside of onBindViewHolder method. How can I create Adapter for once in ViewPagerAdapter ? Is there a solution for this ?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()){


        case 1:
        {
            final ViewHolderMultiple viewHolderMultiple=(ViewHolderMultiple)holder;

            viewHolderMultiple.user_name.setText(list.get(position).getUsername());


            Call<List<DetailPojo>> call = restApiClass.getImages(list.get(position).getId());
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DetailPojo>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<DetailPojo>> call, Response<List<DetailPojo>> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        if (response.body() != null) {

                            imagesList = response.body();
                            postSliderAdapter = new PostSliderAdapter(imagesList, context); //I think my problem is here
                            viewHolderMultiple.postsCircleIndicator.setViewPager(viewHolderMultiple.postsViewPager);

                            Log.i("imageList",imagesList.size()+"");

                        }

                    }

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<LessonPostImagesDetailPojo>> call, Throwable t) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
        break;
        default: break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a method like  onCreate() for RecyclerView Adapter. Because if I can create my second Adapter(for ViewPager) for once in onCreate(),I  can solve my problem.

Comment: You can initiate it in the constructor of the first adapter

Comment: @ItayFeldman yes you are right. But when I initiate it in the constructor of the first adapter, myImageList is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the ViewPager height to hardcode(400dp) from wrap_content and it works. I was trying to change ViewPager height dynamically according to images size, so my ViewPager size was wrap_content. So problem was wrap_content. But I didn't understand why. It's too strange.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Mehmet Pls use this method..  **rv.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 0);**  it may be helpful.. see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool#summary) link for method description..

Comment: hey. Thanks for the answer. I tried this when I call the Adapter but the same problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all dont call api in onbindviewholder create a separate function of Api calling in activity and in bindviewholder call that function like this:
((MainActivity)context).funGetData(); before calling api check if your arraylist is not empty then call api else show data from your previously loaded arraylist.
make getdata public in your main activity and set adapter to viewpager in onsuccess method as you have done.  replace switch with if condition in onbindview holder and dont forget to write its else part. After making these changes let me know.